# Error when converting Value* to PointerType in llvm pass

Tags: instrumentation, llvm-ir

I try to instrument load/store instructions in LLVM IR and trace their memory address, therefore I need to insert instrumentation function to record the address of load/store instructions.

I have a type conversion problem when I try to create recordLoad/Store function:

First, I create pointer type, "**VoidPtrType**"

```
Type Int64Type = IntegerType::getInt64Ty(M.getContext());
Type* VoidPtrType = PointerType::getUnqual(Int64Type);
```

Then, I create arguments for instrumented function:

```
// ldstInst is a load/store instruction
Value* Args[] = {
    ConstantInt::get(Int64Type, uint64_t(lsIDpass->getlsID(inst))),
    ConstantInt::get(VoidPtrType, uint64_t(ldstInst->getPointerOperand())),
    ConstantInt::get(Int64Type, uint64_t(DL->getTypeStoreSize(VTy)))
};
```

However, when I run my program, I can not pass "**ConstantInt::get(VoidPtrType, uint64_t(ldstInst->getPointerOperand()))**", the error message is provided below:

```
Assertion failed: isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"
```

Could anyone provide me any hints?

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `VoidPtrType` is not of `IntegerType` (instead, it's of `PointerType`). I believe that you need to use `inttoptr` cast to create a constant pointer.

Though, I'm not sure about your design. Do you really want to use pointer to LLVM Operand, which exists only at compile time, in your compiled program?

Comment: Thanks. My design is used to trace memory accesses of load/store instructions at runtime. Therefore, I need to insert some custom functions into llvm ir to record addresses. It is like a custom llvm-gprof.